# What are my options for travelling from Neufchâteau, France to Joan of Arc's birthplace in Domrémy-la-Pucelle?

Tags: france, transportation, rural

I'm looking into visiting Joan of Arc's birthplace in Domrémy-la-Pucelle, and as far as I can tell my best bet for getting there is taking the train to Neufchâteau in France. However, once in Neufchâteau I don't see any obvious options for actually getting to Domrémy-la-Pucelle. I could walk, but according to Google Maps that would take over two hours, which sounds a bit long. I could also take the taxi, but according to the sources I can find online that would cost me around 60 Euros back and forth, which sounds like a lot of money given how short the trip is. Another option — which I would like to avoid — is doing the entire trip by car.

Apart from the previously mentioned methods, what are my options for getting from Neufchâteau, France to Domrémy-la-Pucelle?

Comment: Where is your actual starting off point? There seems to be some bus services to Domrémy-la-Pucelle https://www.goticketo.fr/bus/domremy-la-pucelle,lorraine/

Comment: @Newbyte Ok, so your train route is Karlsruhe direct to Neufchâteau?

Comment: Note that in most of France (not in Paris), taxis have one-way and return rates. The first is usually exactly the double of the second. So depending on how long you plan to stay, it may make more sense to ask the taxi to wait (and pay for the wait) rather than pay two one-way rides. But I’m not even sure there are taxis in Neufchâteau.

Comment: @Traveller It's not a direct route from Karlsruhe to Neufchâteau (two stops). There's no particular thing binding me to Neufchâteau either, it's just what the website I used suggested when I tried to find transit to Domrémy-la-Pucelle.

Comment: Note that the Meuse (large river flowing through northeastern France, Belgium and the Netherlands) actually flows through the village (very close to Jeanne d’Arc’s place of birth), but it does not look to be navigable in that area (it’s still a small river at this stage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can not find buses to Domrémy-la-Pucelle, (there may still be,) and taxis from the nearest stations may well be expensive, you can go the last bit by bicycle.

Google found me a bike rental in Neufchâteau. There might well be more, I am not familiar with the place.

That is a 12 km (7.5 mile) bike ride.

Other options may be a partial bus ride and walk for the rest, as mentioned in the question a taxi (and unless you plan to be there long, it can be advisable to ask the taxi to wait) or hiking all 12 km. Or hitch hiking, which comes with the normal warning to only do it when you would do it at home and know what you are doing.

And lastly, if it is not cycling weather, you can contact one of the businesses in Domrémy-la-Pucelle and ask them how to get there from 'here'. Places to stay often have that information on their websites but I did not find those websites yet.